# appContext.getBean me devuelve un proxy y no el objeto manager que estoy buscando

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Buenas, estoy retocando una aplicación antigua y necesito hacer una llamada a la base de datos para recuperar una información.

Esta hecha en java, spring e hibernate.

tengo estas variables.

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

private UsuariosManager usuariosManager;

y la llamada la estoy realizando asi.
UsuariosManager usuariosManager = (UsuariosManager) appContext.getBean("usuarioManager");

me esta devolviendo un proxy, y no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, no se si debo cambiar algo o tratar lo que recupero como el proxy y luego sacar los datos de el.

Saludos y Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No conozco tu configuración XML, pero intenta inyectando tu ApplicationContext de esta manera:

```
private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("alguna/ruta/dondeEstaTuArchivoDeConfiguracion/application-context.xml");
```

Usualmente deberia estar en resource.

Espero te ayude.